# Tasker JavaScriptlet prepending "undefined" in String

Tags: tasker, javascript

I maintain shows, and films from several platforms within an OrgMode File.
Now the string you get when sharing from netflix has unnecessary information.[image: Netflix Shared Link in Orgzly]

I get rid of that with Tasker and a Java Scriptlet.

```
var endName = astext.search(" auf Netflix gesehen?") -1;
var text = astext.slice(15,endName);
endName = endName+24;
var replacer = astext.slice(0,endName);
var link = String(astext.replace(replacer));
```

With `astext` as input source from AutoShare Netflix Toast Interception.

So far so good, but as I have actually never used JavaScript before I get to a problem I don't really understand.

Infront of my string stored in `link` there is "undefinded" prepended.
I don't really know if I mess up JavaScript syntax or if there is something special with the interpreter Tasker is using.
[image: undefined String prepended]

This also happens if I instead of "resharing" the link simply print it out via `Flash` Task in Tasker

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with scripts in Tasker but if it uses common JavaScript then you should be able to remove the text before the URL easily using this script:

```
var idx = astext.indexOf("https://");
var link = astext.substring(0,idx);
```

First search for the string `https://` and save the start index. Then cut everything away from start to the saved index.